# How to push a wix burn exe to Active Directory?

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

Active directory allows MSI be pushed on to client computers.

How can we push WiX burn exe installers to remote AD computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy through Active Directory Group Policy, you must use a [ZAP file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZAP_File).